# How to set price for In App product for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I creating IAP for my Windows Phone 8 application. But field "Base price" is disabled and I can't change it. 
So what I need to do for creating paid IAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "Base Price" option is disabled, check for text immediately below it. Does it say:

> You’ll need to provide your tax or bank info (or both) if you want to
>   submit paid in-app products.

You must provide the necessary information for you to be paid before you can release paid products.

Comment: Even when this is done, the field is disabled the first time you create an In-App product it seems (bug probably). Solution: 1. Fill in tax-info. 2. Create in-app product. 3. Save product. 4. Go back and edit it (now you can change the price).

Answer (score 4):

Also, if your application is marked as Beta I think the option to set a product price is disabled. Once you get your app properly certified and in the public store I believe it becomes active...

Comment: If that's true, it's kind of weird... Why should I wait until my app is approved with settings correct prices for in-app products?

Comment: I know. I thought the same but its true. As soon as mine came out of beta it was fine.Maybe its to prevent you charging beta testers for IAP?

Answer (score 0):

Also if submission is in progress (even if no package was uploaded and the submission was not actually done, basically if step 1 is checked) then the details and prices cannot be changed.
You can cancel the submission (you wont loose anything since you have not actually submitted anything) and then make any change you like.